# Instantiating the class that contains static void Main()

Tags: c#, static, console-application, instance, program-entry-point

I am reviewing a co-worker's C# console app, and I see this snippet:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        p.RealMain();
    }

    ... non-static RealMain function
}
```

Presumably, he's doing this because he wants to have instance-level fields, etc.

I haven't seen this before, but this style bugs me.  Is it a common and accepted practice?

Comment: What's wrong with this? What do you have against instance variables? Do you never use them?

Comment: Seems weird to me, but I can't tell you with authority if it's common or good.

Comment: @David Heffernan -- I don't have any solid argument for or against this (just like @ThatMatthew).  It's just that static fields are just as easy to use, and you wouldn't have to instantiate the outer class.

Comment: @David Heffernan He doesn't have a problem with instance variables in general. He has a problem with instantiating a class that is normally just used to call a static method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a school of thought that says that the main() function of object oriented code should do as little as possible. Main() is an "ugly" throwback to procedural code design, where programs were written in one function, calling subroutines only as necessary. In OOP, all code should be encapsulated in objects that do their jobs when told.

So, by doing this, you reduce the LOC in the main() entry point to two lines, and the real logic of the program is structured and executed in a more O-O fashion.

Comment: So when you yourself write console apps, is this what you do?

Comment: No. Didn't say I *subscribed* to that school of thought :)

Answer (score 6):

It makes sense to me.

In particular, you may want to add *just* enough logic into `Main` to parse the command line arguments - possibly using a generalized argument parser - and then pass those options into the constructor in a strongly-typed way suitable for the program in question.

Albin asked why this would be necessary. In a word: testability. In some cases it's entirely feasible to *at least* test some aspects of a top level program with unit tests or possibly integration tests. Using instance fields instead of static fields (etc) improves the testability here, as you don't need to worry about previous test runs messing up the state.

Comment: So when you yourself write console apps, is this what you do?

Comment: @anonymous: Sometimes, yes. It all depends on the situation, but I definitely think it makes sense, particularly if it keep testing cleaner. The smaller the project, the more sense it makes - if your project only contains a couple of classes, having an extra one for Main is unnecessary clutter IMO.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to get `non static functions` you have to do like this.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program(); // dependency of the class will be there.So not a good practice
        p.RealMain();// if you want initalize, you have to go like this or better you can do it in some other class.
    }

    void RealMain(){} 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Never seen it before. If you want to go with this pattern, create a separate `Program2`-class with `RealMain` and instantiate that instead.

Why do you need instance level fields? Is static fields not enough?

There could be a benefit if you internally want to instantiate many `Program` classes.

I don't see anything particularly wrong with this approach, I just don't have seen it before.

Comment: "Why do you need instance level fields? Is static fields not enough?" -- Good question.  I guess I'll have to ask the developer, but it's hard for me to imagine a situation that would warrant multiple instances of Program each with their own non-static fields.  It's just a console app.

Answer (score 1):

Application entry point is always defined as `static void Main(...)`.
You can decide to write your code inside Main() or use this method to run something else located elsewhere... it's up to you decide...

Answer (score 1):

The accepted practice is to create an instance of a separate class which can contain anything you need. The above snippet looks weird at least :).

Comment: Accepted by who, exactly? Any references?

Comment: @Jon Skeet By "accepted" I meant that this practice is used almost everywhere, the Main method usually serves as an entry point to an application itself, for example in Windows applications where a form is instantiated first and then a "real" entry point method - Show - is called.

Comment: @Centro: It really depends on what you're doing. For small tools, I'll usually only have the one class - whether that's instantiated or not. I don't think there's any benefit in having two classes rather than one, just to avoid having `Main` in the same class.

Comment: @Jon Skeet For small applications maybe it makes sense, but for real-world applications the Main method must be as clear as possible.

Comment: @Centro: What makes you think that real world applications can't be small? I've written loads of small tools which are very much used in the real world. Of course, a large proportion of applications don't have a `Main` method at all - they're web applications, or web services or whatever.

Comment: @Jon Skeet When an application does a real work, it must have classes with their responsibilities for doing that work. The responsibility of the Program class is just to initiate other responsibilities. Of course, for simple apps it does not matter and you can have all logic in the Main method only.

Comment: @Centro: That doesn't do much for testability, does it? The scope for tools which only span a few classes, but where you want to be able to test them (and thus want instances rather than static methods, to keep state separate between tests) is pretty broad IMO.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Surely, it's better to use instances for testing rather than static methods if it's what you meant.

Comment: @Centro: Yes. Rather than use a bunch of static methods in a single class, use a bunch of *instance* methods in a single class, and make `Main` just create an instance of that class (passing in any appropriate configuration etc). Now that class *could* be a separate one, but I don't actually see much benefit of putting `Main` in a class on its own if the only purpose for it is to instantiate a different one and say "go".

Answer (score 0):

If it was any other class but "Program" the question wouldn't have come up. This design gives you the opportunity to instantiate multiple instances of "Program", maybe threaded in the future, so why not. I'm with KeithS here: As few as possible in static void Main.

Answer (score 0):

I see this a lot, particularly for quick console programs knocked up to try something out, or test something.

Visual Studio practically encourages it - if you ask for a new Console program, it generates a single file, with a class containing only a Main method.

Unless you are doing something complicated, which requires more than 1 class, or something very simple, which doesn't require a class at all (i.e. all methods and variables static)
why would you not do it this way?